# Understanding converters as a managed beans

Tags: jsf, converters, managed-bean, mojarra

Mojarra 2.2.12

In facelets I have the following `SelectOneMenu`, wrapped in a custom tag:

```
<ui:composition>
    <ui:param name="value" value="#{value}" />
    <ui:param name="collection" value="#{collection}" />
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{value}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{collection}" />
        <f:converter binding="#{myConverter}"/> 
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</ui:composition>
```

and here is the actual tag-definition:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>selector</tag-name>
    <attribute>
        <name>value</name>
        <type>ucom.adg.utils.ui.jsf.CollectionHolder</type>
        <required>true</required>
        <description>A value expression the selected item is going to be bound to</description>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>collection</name>
        <type>java.lang.List</type>
        <required>true</required>>
        <description>The list all items to be displayed in the drop-down-list.
        </description>
    </attribute>
    <source>../resources/tags/selector.xhtml</source>
</tag>
```

where converter is implemented as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyConverter implements Converter{

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{myDao}")
    private MyDao myDao;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        //do some
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        //do some
    }
    // GET, SET
}
```

So, the issue I came across is that the `h:selectOneMenu` is being restored with the `MyConverter` having `myDao` property setted to `null` causing `NullPointException` to be thrown. `context.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getSession().getAttribute("platformSelectorConverter")` in turn returns the conveter with setted `myDao` to the actual `Dao`.

So I start debugging the `RestoreViewPhase` and figured out that restoring the state of the component is being performed by the [UIComponentBase# processRestoreState(FacesContext, Object)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.2/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.java#UIComponentBase.processRestoreState%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%2Cjava.lang.Object%29).

In the case of the `HtmlSelectOneMenu` it ends up in [StateHolderSaver#restore](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.2/javax/faces/component/StateHolderSaver.java#StateHolderSaver.restore%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29). And the following piece of code is called to restore the convertor:

```
public Object restore(FacesContext context) throws IllegalStateException {
    Object result = null;
    Class toRestoreClass;
    //some code ommited 
    try {
        toRestoreClass = loadClass(className, this);
    }
    //catches
    if (null != toRestoreClass) {
    try {
        result = toRestoreClass.newInstance(); //Creating a new instance,
                                          // that's why the Dao is null
    }
    //ommmited
    return result;
}
```

My question is why doesn't Mojarra try to get the converter from session, but creates a new instance instead and how to fix that?

Comment: Why isn't your converter serializable in first place? Or differently put, why is it session scoped? Can't it better be request or application scoped depending on how DAO is implemented?

Comment: @BalusC _Why isn't your converter serializable in first place?_ Didn't know that converters had to be Serializable. Why is it necessary? _why is it session scoped?_ To avoid wasting the time to recreating the same converter. The Dao is a prototype-scoped spring bean.

Comment: @BalusC BTW, The tag is used on pages with view-scoped beans. Is that also important? I thought it wasn't...

Comment: @BalusC Is it even possible to fix that somehow? I think now that `SessionScope`d beans is not suitable for converters because mojarra will recreate their instances for each request.

Comment: Converters don't need to be serializable. Session scoped beans need to be. Otherwise they won't be saved in the state. If converter (and DAO) is stateless, just make it application scoped if your only concern is cost of instantiating.

Comment: @BalusC Wonderful, you're right, as always thank you. I made the Converter implementing `Serializable` and it worked, thank you. May I ask you one more question. Perhaps I missed it, but don't you know where the checking for exisitng saved state  (e.g. session-scoped converter) is being performed for the component?

Comment: Can't tell from top of head right now, but I can at least tell that making them session scoped is not the best approach. It's likely to unnecessarily accumulate or perhaps even leak memory. A standard `@FacesConverter` is inherently request scoped. So, ideally, you'd like to make them `@RequestScoped`. You could theoretically make it `@ApplicationScoped` if it's stateless.

Comment: Just looking into it, but can't reproduce your initial problem. Any settings in web.xml different from defaults?

Comment: @BalusC I use jspx suffixes with JSF 2.2 that required to set some tricky combination of parameters like `DEFAULT_SUFFIX` etc to make JSF 2 work correctly. Also, there are some richfaces-related parameters. Is that what you mean? Or you meant some specific parameters?

Comment: @BalusC Probably, the only way to figured out what exactly was wrong is to find the place where making decision about retrieving_serialized/creating_new_instance is performed. I haven't looked for it yet because now it works fine. If I find something out, I'll write it here.

Comment: Imagine me having a project with most minimal settings (i.e. completely empty web/faces-config/beans.xml) and most recent versions (currently Mojarra 2.2.12 and Tomcat 8.0.27 and Weld 2.3.0) and trying to reproduce the problem based on solely the information provided so far in the question.